# Restricting git merges if the PR title doesn't match JIRA story id

Tags: git, gitlab, github-actions, jira

I have a requirement to implement checks in git merges if the PR title doesn't contain Jira Story id. Here's what I've implemented so far in the github workflow

```
name: "PR Title Check"
on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]

  pull_request:
     types: [opened, edited, synchronize]
jobs:
  check-title:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Check PR title
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      with:
        github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        
        script: |
          const payload = context.payload
          const prTitle = payload.pull_request.title
          // The pattern for JIRA ticket format
          const jiraPattern = /[A-Z]+-\d+/g
          
          if (!jiraPattern.test(prTitle)) {
            console.log('The PR title does not match JIRA ticket format! The correct format is XX-XXXX <Story Details>')
            // Fails the workflow
            core.setFailed('PR title does not match JIRA ticket format! The correct format is XX-XXXX <Story Details>')
          } else {
            console.log('PR title format is correct.')
          }
```

based on this article I read - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/enforcing-jira-ticket-formatting-in-github-pr-titles-and-commit-messages-78d9755568df

The problem with above code is that it doesn't let me merge code from `x <- y`. What am I doing wrong? The restriction should be only merges to dev branch.